# Google play store giving app rejection error for SSL Handler cordova app 6.4.0

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, gps

I have created an app on Google Play Store and uploaded APK.But as in my APK I have modified SSL handler method,GPS(Google play store)rejected app saying-

**We rejected ABC, with package name org.AbcApp, for violating our Malicious Behavior or User Data policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play. WebView SSL Error Handler is vulnerable**

When I tried to keep default SSL handler in app file,then also GPS rejected an app.
*Im using Cordova 6.4.0 version.*
So can you please suggest if this is cordova issue or anything else?TIA

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: are you using cordova-plugin-file?

Comment: @jcesarmobile - Did you mean "cordova-plugin-certificates"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant cordova-plugin-file-transfer. There is a known issue that Google doesn't allow this plugin because it allows uploads to unsafe server's, even if you don't use this feature the code is there. Anyway, can you list the plugins you use?

Comment: @jcesarmobile - I haven't used "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" explicitly. I have just added "InAppBrowser" plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove **onReceivedSslError**.After removing **onReceivedSslError** from **SystemWebViewClient**,it is accepted by google play store.Thanks.